# How do I remove instance methods at runtime in Objective-C 2.0?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

Is it possible to remove methods added to a class with class_addMethod?

Or if I want to do this, must I keep creating classes at runtime with objc_allocateClassPair  and adding different sets of methods to them to vary the methods implemented?

I'll accept answers that include hackery :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, you can't.

You could in the Objective-C 1.0 ABI/API via:

```
OBJC_EXPORT void class_removeMethods(Class, struct objc_method_list *) OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

But that function was removed in Objective-C 2.0 because removing methods is pretty much never the right answer.   Certainly not often enough to justify the overhead incurred by supporting said feature.

Also removed from the ObjC2.0 ABI was the ability to directly access the class/method structures.  They are now opaque so that they can be changed in the future without breaking binary compatibility.

What you could do, though, is use a custom proxy that varies the set of methods that it responds to.   See documentation for the NSProxy class; http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Of course, this question begs the question "What are you trying to do?".   Such on the fly meta-programming is atypical.  Once a class is instantiated, it isn't normally considered desirable to change the set of methods it responds to under the assumption that previous instantiations may still depend on said methods.

Comment: The answer to "why" is that I am interested in writing some code that will show what happens when KVC is used. By adding and removing methods at runtime I could allow the user to explore the effect of having various combinations of methods present.

I have concluded that only way this can be done is by mucking about with the internals; and Objective-C 2.0 puts a stop to that by all means except hackery.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but: Maybe in your sample you could dynamically create subclasses at runtime that respond to the methods you want. Instead of removing a method, you could then simply create a new subclass of your base class that does not have that method.

Comment: Another case where deleting a method is needed: In unit tests you sometimes need to stub out methods in existing classes. The OCMock framework allows you to do this, but OCMock itself has a hard time restoring the class after an individual test because it can't remove methods. It can replace the IMP of an existing method with the stub, but if the method was in a parent class, it needs to add the stub in the subclass and then can't get rid of it. So, to respond to the "What are you trying to do?" question: I totally get "opinionated software" but in my opinion Apple's runtime shouldn't be it.

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg Interesting problem;  it isn't so much that the runtime is being opinionated, it is that it is focused on performance and stability.   Removing methods requires a lot of additional engineering effort to not grossly impact performance while also being something that is done often enough to justify the effort of supporting it.   However, the pattern of use you describe is obviously of value.  Please file an enhancement request describing that need (and post the bug # here).

Comment: What about dynamically subclassing and adding methods you need and changing the class of an object to that instance. Every time you need to remove a method, recreate the dynamic subclass to not have the removed method.

Comment: @LeoNatan Removing a method from a subclass doesn't makes sense, though.  If the superclass does `if ([self isKindOfClass:[ClassWithMethod class]) [self methodRemovedInSubclass:];` where `self` is really a kind of the subclass with the method removed, then the app will crash.

Comment: I meant for the OCMock case proposed above. If OCMock would dynamically subclass and add methods, it can tear down the dynamic subclass by restoring to the original and create a new one without the replaced implementation.

Comment: @LeoNatan Oh, right.  Yes.  Or don't even bother tearing down the subclass at all?

Comment: Sure, it will come in handy later if needed. One could work a scheme where the name of the class is constructed by which method exists and which doesn't and just create them as needed, and replace an object's class.

Answer (score 16):

You can't exactly "remove" a method, but you can get the same effect as a removal, by making the method just redirect everything to the message forwarding path (the code that will eventually call `-forwardInvocation:`). There are two ways to accomplish that:

1. `_objc_msgForward()`, declared in `/usr/include/objc/message.h` but not included in the online documentation, can be used as the `IMP` for your method you are trying to remove. Because it's undocumented, it may be considered private or unsupported.
2. You can call [class_getMethodImplementation()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW3) with a selector that you know does not exist, and use the result as the `IMP` for the method you are trying to remove. Based on the documentation, this should have the same effect as the first option:

> The function pointer returned may be a function internal to the runtime instead of an actual method implementation. For example, if instances of the class do not respond to the selector, the function pointer returned will be part of the runtime's message forwarding machinery.

In either case, it becomes as simple as:

```
method_setImplementation(methodToRemove, forwardingIMP);
```

Note that this will basically block out any superclass implementations, so you'll have to be more careful if any superclass might have a valid implementation that you want to keep. In such a case, you could get the `IMP` from the superclass or something similar.