# Objective-C Runtime: How to remove a method from a class?

Tags: objective-c-runtime

In the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), I see `class_addMethod` but not `class_removeMethod`. How do I dynamically remove a method?

Also, does `class_addMethod` add an instance method or a class method?

Comment: Given ObjC's Smalltalk genes, my guess is be that `class_addMethod` adds an instance method, and that to add a class method, you need to add an instance method to the class' class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove instance methods at runtime in Objective-C 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315169/how-do-i-remove-instance-methods-at-runtime-in-objective-c-2-0)

Answer (score 5):

As Inerdial mentioned in his comment, the main question (How can a method be removed from a class at runtime?) is somewhat exhaustively answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315169/how-do-i-remove-instance-methods-at-runtime-in-objective-c-2-0).

MattDiPasquale asks as well:

> Also, does class_addMethod add an instance method or a class method?

Inerdial is correct again:

> class_addMethod adds an instance method, and that to add a class method, you need to add an instance method to the class' class.

Given a *Class* c, we can get our hands on the class of which it is an instance (known as its "metaclass") as simply as

```
Class metac = object_getClass(c);
```

To then "add a class method" to c, we add a method to metac using class_addMethod.

If, for example, elsewhere we have already defined

```
id myClassMethodImplementation(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    //implementation
}
```

We can then add a class method to c as follows:

```
BOOL success = class_addMethod(metac, @selector(myClassMethod), (IMP)myClassMethodImplementation, "@@:");
```

or equivalently

```
BOOL success = class_addMethod(object_getClass(c), @selector(myClassMethod), (IMP)myClassMethodImplementation, "@@:");
```

To simply add this same method as an *instance* method on c, we simply write

```
BOOL success = class_addMethod(c, @selector(myClassMethod), (IMP)myClassMethodImplementation, "@@:");
```

References:
1.  [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)    2.  [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide - Type Encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)    3.  [Cocoa with Love - What is a meta-class in Objective-C?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)