# Temporarily disable message handling by an instance - ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, message

I have a class inheriting the `UICollectionViewCell`. In this class I implemented `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` selectors. This allowed me to implement dragging of the cells.

Later I decided to use the same cells implementation in another view hosting another CollectionView. The behavior of the cells are exactly the same but the touches handling should be disabled since I want to allow the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of the CollectionView delegate to be called when the user taps a cell in this view ( instead of the custom dragging as in the previous view ).

Having if inside the `touchesBegan/Moved` functions is not an option since the fact that those methods are present "steals" the messages and they no longer trigger the selection inside the `UICollectionView` ....

I tried to forward the messages to the view but it is a mess ...

What I am looking for is to somehow dinamically set that my instances of the cell do not react to the "`touchesBegan/Moved`" messages

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315169/how-do-i-remove-instance-methods-at-runtime-in-objective-c-2-0) but it is not exactly the same ....

Comment: It think you should not steal the messages from the collection view. Do you call `[super ...]` in your `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods?

Comment: @Tobi - no. I will try. I understand it will call the upper class, but will it actually help the message to travel to the CollectionView ? How can I implement dragging of the cell without stealing events from the Collection? I more than ready to do it right way . thanks

Comment: As I said I think you're views shouldn't steal the events from the collection view even if you override the `touches...` methods. Every view already implements the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods weather you override them or not since it is a subclass of `UIResponder`. But if you don't call super in your custom implementation your override the default implementation of them (according to the documentation, the default implementation does nothing, but I'm not sure if the doc is up to date) maybe that's causing the 'stealing' of the events.